# goroutine reading from channel with dynamic loop getting waitgroup is reused before previous was has returned

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I am working on a small utility which needs to iterate over a dynamic range of items (can be 100 or can be 100000) and put the items in a channel. From that channel another function reads the items and does some processing on each item individually.
I am trying to use `sync.WaitGroup` to make sure that my utility does not exit before all the items in the channels are processed. As I am fairly new to channels and waitgroups, I am stuck with an error `panic: sync: WaitGroup is reused before previous Wait has returned`

https://play.golang.org/p/nMw3END_9qw

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/dchest/uniuri"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
var count = 0

func printMe(msg string) {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(count, msg)
}

func makeMePrint(ch chan string) {
    for s := range ch {
        count++
        wg.Add(1)
        printMe(s)
        wg.Done()
    }

}

func writePrint(ch chan<- string) {
    fmt.Println("Starting to insert data in channel")
    for i := 1; i <= rand.Intn(30); i++ {
        s := uniuri.New()
        ch <- s
    }
    fmt.Println("We are done inserting all data in the channel")
    close(ch)
}

func main() {

    var ch = make(chan string)

    go writePrint(ch)
    go makeMePrint(ch)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

This is the main idea of what I am working on (not the exact code but exactly the same architecture with same number of functions).

How can I make sure that the utility only exits only when all the items in the channel are processes.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is no need for a waitgroup here, simply use the channel close event for this. Once all items are sent on the channel, the "producer" should close the channel. Workers may use `for range` on the channel, which terminates when all items are received from the channel (that were sent on it before it was closed).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do with the `WaitGroup` here. Take a look at the documentation example: https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#example_WaitGroup

Comment: Your wait group isn't doing anything, except creating a race condition which you're running into.

Comment: To be clear on my first comment: you don't need a waitgroup to get all elements from the channel, but you might need a waitgroup if you need to wait all your workers to finish.

Comment: Like @icza said if you want to close your application after everything is executed (is not a part of some bigger application and work in background), you can remove `go` which is before `makeMePrint` and after that you can safely remove all of waitGroup usage because `range` in `makeMePrint` will end after you close the channel

Comment: The above comments are right regarding an improved design not using WaitGroup, but regarding your original error, it is because the call to `wg.Wait` is being executed before any call to `wg.Add` gets executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/dchest/uniuri"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var count = 0

func printMe(msg string) {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(count, msg)
}

func makeMePrint(wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan string) {
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Done()

    for s := range ch {
        count++
        printMe(s)

    }

}

func writePrint(wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan<- string) {
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Done()

    fmt.Println("Starting to insert data in channel")
    for i := 1; i <= rand.Intn(30); i++ {
        s := uniuri.New()
        ch <- s
    }
    fmt.Println("We are done inserting all data in the channel")
    close(ch)
}

func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    var ch = make(chan string)

    go writePrint(wg, ch)
    go makeMePrint(wg, ch)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    wg.Wait()
}
```